# wso2 micro integrator clustering for a service - creating another question, since first one was closed for no eason

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-micro-integrator, wso2-esb

Let's say we have a micro integrator communicating with several services.

We want to be able to cluster one of the services, for example if we send two requests to a service we want each of these requests to be processed by a different node of a service, is that possible?

Services are third party REST API, we want to send requests to two different URL.

There is Load-BalanceEndPoint element in the Integration studio element, but it's not clear how it works, or even if it permit us to solve the issue above.

Could anyone help us resolve this problem/explain how we should use mentioned endpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use Load-Balance Endpoint for your usecase. Have a look at the following sample configurations.

**API configuration :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/loadbalance" name="checkLoadBalance" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="GET">
        <inSequence>
            <call>
                <endpoint key="testLoadBalance"/>
            </call>
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

**Endpoint Configuration :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoint name="testLoadBalance" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <loadbalance algorithm="org.apache.synapse.endpoints.algorithms.RoundRobin">
        <endpoint name="endpoint_urn_uuid_6179155B57847314A657084710149040-304004407">
            <http method="GET" uri-template="http://www.mocky.io/v2/5e574b1c3000006000fd38cd">
                <suspendOnFailure>
                    <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
                    <progressionFactor>1</progressionFactor>
                </suspendOnFailure>
                <markForSuspension>
                    <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
                </markForSuspension>
            </http>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint name="endpoint_urn_uuid_6179155B57847314A657084710149040-304004407">
            <http method="GET" uri-template="http://www.mocky.io/v2/5185415ba171ea3a00704eed">
                <suspendOnFailure>
                    <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
                    <progressionFactor>1</progressionFactor>
                </suspendOnFailure>
                <markForSuspension>
                    <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
                </markForSuspension>
            </http>
        </endpoint>
    </loadbalance>
    <description/>
</endpoint>
```

Here I have used two different mocky endpoints. They will return *{"Hello": "World"}* and *{"hello": "world"}*.
After deploying, if I invoke checkLoadBalance API for first time, I will get response from the first endpoint. If I invoke for the second time, I will get response from the second endpoint. Here I have given the algorithm as Roundrobin. Hence it will scheduled in a RoundRobin manner.